# SerialPort.Write method with sbyte[]

Tags: c#

I am writing data to a serial port using C# MSVS2013. But SerialPort write method only excepts b[] or char[] or string text. Is there any method to send sbyte[]. Beacuse my data is in sbyte[] which is having some negative and some positive numbers and when converting sbyte[] to byte[] it causes loss of data. Any one can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Converting from `sbyte[]` to `byte[]` won't cause a loss of data. Sure, -1 will become 255, but the bits will still all be set...

Comment: device is designed to understand a fixed template. Which includes command then total length followed by actual length of data then followed by data and end command. while calculating data length or actual length the unsigned bytes are giving problem so I'm keeping every thing in signed byte[]. And at last converting final sbyte[] to byte[] for writing it causes data lose.Is there any way to send data without converting it to unsigned byte[]. If you can give me any idea or hint then also I can find some thing.

Comment: As I've said, converting from `sbyte[]` to `byte[]` shouldn't cause any data loss. If you claim it does, please provide a [mcve].